# Error trying to install my webcam

Tags: permissions, webcam

I downloaded the "gspca" video for linux (v4l1) driver but when I tried to compile it, the terminal showed the following error:

```
$ cd gspcav1-20071224/
$ ~/gspcav1-20071224
$ ./gspca_build
bash: ./gspca_build: permission denied
```

I have no clue why I don't have permission in my own machine.

Comment: you need to use the "sudo" command to do certain admin things. try that followed by your password

Comment: Can I ask why you needed to download the gspca driver? What webcam are you using and what version of Ubuntu are you trying?

Comment: The webcam is ID 0c45:602e Microdia VideoCAM Messenger and i can't make it work. I'm trying ubuntu 12.04

Comment: I can use the webcam with Cheese but not with skype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to grant execution permissions to the file. There are several ways to allow a file to be executed as a program :

- Using Nautilus file manager, right click on your script file `gspca_build` and select *Properties*. Then go to the *Permissions* tab and check *Allow executing file as program*.

[image]

- Using the command line, open a terminal and set `gspca_build` directory as your current directory. Then type the following command :

  ```
  sudo chmod +x gspca_build
  ```

You should now be able to execute your script.

Answer (score 0):

Type

```
cd gspcav1-20071224/
~/gspcav1-20071224
$ sudo ./gspca_build
```